# C++ - passing a pointer to a function and using it as an argument to another function

Tags: c++, sdl-2

i am currently reentering programming in C++ to write a small game. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and SDL2. I am following a series of tutorials to get into SDL. My problem seems to be related to me not entirely understanding the workings of pointers in c++. I am passing a pointer to a function as an argument and want to use it within this function as an argument to another function which returns a pointer to a SDL_Surface. Following my code:

init SDL:

```
SDL_Surface* init(SDL_Window *window)
{
  SDL_Surface *screenSurface = nullptr;
  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
  {
    printf("%s", "Error in init");    
  }
  else
  {   
    screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
  }

  return screenSurface;
}
```

load bmp:

```
SDL_Surface* loadMedia(const char file[])
{
  SDL_Surface *image = SDL_LoadBMP(file);
  if (image == nullptr)
  {
    printf("%s", "Error in loadMedia");
  }
  return image;
}
```

main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("xyz", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
  SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

  SDL_Surface *screenSurface = init(window);
  if (screenSurface == nullptr)
  {
    printf("%s", "surface is null");
  }

  SDL_Surface *image = loadMedia("resources/images/village.bmp");
  SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, screenSurface, NULL);

  SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
  SDL_Delay(1000);

  SDL_FreeSurface(image);
  image = nullptr;
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  window = nullptr;
  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;
}
```

if i create

```
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("xyz",...)
```

as a global variable and initialize it within init(), everything works fine and screenSurface is initialized with a valid value. As soon as i do as it is in the code, pass the pointer window to init() to create the surface there and then return screenSurface, screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window) returns null.

I have been programming mostly SAS and Java the last years and didnt touch c++ for several years, so im sure its just a minor misunderstanding on my side but i cannot figure out what it is.

Thx in advance :)

Comment: Shouldn't `SDL_Init()` be called before `SDL_CreateWindow()` ?

Comment: omg, that was it. *shame. thx for that quick answer, i must have missed it when i was changing the tutorial to not have the SDL variables being global